# Yahoo Calendar API iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, yahoo-api

I want to sync my app with yahoo calendar such that the events added in the app are directly added in the user's yahoo calendar. is there any api available?

I have tried http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/objectivec/ but it hasn't helped me much.

Comment: I suspect if you do some additional searching in the search bar at http://developer.yahoo.com you might find some useful hints there, too (e.g. keywords like "Yahoo+Calendar").

Comment: i am working on it since 3 days.. and i did try at developer.yahoo.com.. but i did not get anything..

Comment: @xxnationss What? Nothing? Not even an API for calendar access?

Comment: http://calendar.yahoo.com/?v=60&view=d&type=20&title=Australia%20Day%20lunch&st=20080126T060000Z&dur=0115&desc=A%20traditional%20barbeque%20for%20our%20big%20day&in_loc=On%20your%20local%20beach   I got this.. but it first redirects to yahoo.com and then on click on save.. it adds events.. But i dont want that..

Comment: You know, there are several smart-aleck answers, but neither is correct or helpful. The Yahoo! API seems to have nothing about accessing calendar events except iCalendar, which doesn't allow adding events. I know this doesn't help, but I landed here looking for a similar thing. I don't think it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo Calendar supports CalDav. I think you need to look into using that. There doesn't seem to be a native Yahoo API for accessing their Calendars.

Edit: maybe this can help? http://sope.opengroupware.org/en/sope_ical/index.html